# How to iterate through list in Where clause in C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net

I have this part of code:

```
using (var context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
{
    return await context
        .Xxxx
        .SetTracking(false)
        .Where(t => t.Id == xxxId)
        .Select(t => new ResultsByIdSqlModel(
            xxxId,
            t.Name,
            t.SessionId,...
```

But I am not sure how to modify this when ***xxxId*** is list of Ids as I want to return for each id response.

Answer (score 1):

you would need `Contains`:

```
using (var context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
{
    return await context
        .Xxxx
        .SetTracking(false)
        .Where(t => xxxIdList.Contains( t.Id ) )
        .Select(t => new ResultsByIdSqlModel(
            xxxId,
            t.Name,
            t.SessionId,...
```

The Contains method will be tranlated into `IN` in SQL.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying with IN but not working. This should fix it :)

Comment: Contains is not the best way for matching ids (for example when you
 the use contains also matches
 `1 = 123`, So that, is wrong `Any` is best)
 you should use `Any`:

    using (var context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
    {
        return await context
            .Xxxx
            .SetTracking(false)
            .Where(t => xxxIdList.Any(item => item == t.Id)) )
            .Select(t => new ResultsByIdSqlModel(
                xxxId,
                t.Name,
                t.SessionId,...

Comment: @MuhammadUmar "ontains also matches 1 = 123" no, in this case it does not, because it is called upon a list and not a string consisting of numbers

Comment: 1=123 so that's wrong brother it should be just 1=1 when you use Any

Comment: When you match Id then it should be 1=1